# Adding items into Listbox from a Listview

Tags: vb.net

Public MaintenanceMenuList As ListView

Function AddItems()

```
 Dim lstModules As New ListBox()

 MaintenanceMenuList.Items.Add("item_1")
 lstModules.Items.Add(MaintenanceMenuList)
```

End Function

I am receiving an error like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". What seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MaintenanceMenuList Listview object hasn't been created with a/the New keyword

```
Public MaintenanceMenuList As ListView

Function AddItems()

    Dim lstModules As New ListBox()

    ' if the object is nothing, create it
    If MaintenanceMenuList Is Nothing Then 
        MaintenanceMenuList = New ListView
    End If

    MaintenanceMenuList.Items.Add("item_1")
    lstModules.Items.Add(MaintenanceMenuList)

End Function
```

Also, your function doesn't return anything or mention what type it will be returning...

**EDIT - added response to comment**

Change:

```
lstModules.Items.Add(MaintenanceMenuList)
```

to:

```
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In MaintenanceMenuList.Items
    lstModules.Items.Add(lvi.Text)
Next
```

Comment: The lstModules is displaying this text: 

"System.Windows.Forms.ListView,Items.Count:4,Items[0]:ListViewItem:{item1}"

is it possible to display the text "item_1" only?